# how to get the path of file_get_contents from a php file using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, file-get-contents

is there a way to get/retrieve the value/parameters in a 'file_get_contents' in php file using javascript? my php code is...

```
<?php
  (file_get_contents("http://localhost/" . $_GET["path"] . "?json=" . urlencode($_GET["json"])));
?>
```

i want to display the value inside the 'file_get_contents' in my html using javascript. is there anybody here who could help me? please... thank you..

edit... how to show the xmlhttprequest in my html using javascript? thank you

Comment: Nice, I've been wondering how to do this +1 if you do anwser please post how to seperate the path with explode() +1

Comment: PHP do not have js engine to run js code. And requesting data from your own server is quite nonsense

Comment: You're trying to retrieve information from a file on your server and then displaying that returned information on the page - using JavaScript?

Comment: no, not the returned information, but the url page...or the xmlhttprequest or whatever it is.. it is something like http://localhost/jquerystudy/mine/processjson.php?path=masterData/view&json=%7B%22SessionID%22:%22cT2qGr8WdBfdxvzD9............main_account_group_desc%22}

Comment: let me rephrase my question. how to show the xmlhttprequest in my html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is server side while Javascript is client side.  The only way to get you parameters to js would be to return them via an array in an ajax call (ie. return as json) or echo the parameters to the final page where the js will hold them.

Comment: echo the parameters to the final page?... i already tried that one but the output is in complete. it will not display "http://localhost/....". instead, it will only display the "processjson.php?path=masterData/...."

Comment: something like: `echo "<script>var url = '$url';</script>";` where $url is the php version of the url.  Then you can access it in your js using the `url` variable.

Comment: ok, thank you for that one. i will just update if it will works. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Because the file_get_contents function is processed on the server side before sending the response, there is no way for javascript to access the value of the argument. You could, however, use PHP to write additional HTML (or javascript) that's sent in the response; something like this:

```
  <?php
        echo "<script>var url='http://localhost/" . $_GET["path"] . "?json=" . urlencode($_GET["json"])."';</script>";
    ?>
```

You'd then have a javascript variable with that argument.

Comment: i just try that one and it didn't work the way i want it to be.. it also doesn't display the data. but thank you for the help. :) i want to display something like.... http://localhost/jquerystudy/mine/processjson.php?path=masterData/.....2,%22dataType%22:%22data%22%7D&json={%22SessionID%22:%226nj7pElV4G2zn8pi55atXu3Gj67d7zp....main_account_group_desc%22}